# Incorrect validation context in nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, activemodel

I'm having a problem with a form in Rails 4.1.8. It contains a few attributes from the `Pledge` model and a few more from a `has_one` association called `Grant`. In the controller, `@pledge` is assigned the params and validated with a custom context:

```
@pledge.valid? :wizard
```

The validation doesn't work as expected, because on the pledge, the custom context `:wizard` is used, whereas on the nested grant, the default context `:create` is used. Any ideas why the custom validation context is not passed onto the models nested in the form?